# {PAGENO} resulting in $pageno

Tags: php, mpdf

Using mpdf in a Scriptcase application: 
using mpdf 8.0.0 and php 7.0.22

```
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(  
        [  
            'mode'          => 'utf-8',  
            'format'        => 'A4',  
            'orientation'   => 'P'  
        ]  
    );  
    $mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');  
    $mpdf->SetTitle($product_naam);  
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($content);  

} catch (\Mpdf\MpdfException $e)   
{   
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

results in a string `$pageno` in the footer of my PDF output, instead of giving the page number.
Does anyone have workaround for this issue?

Comment: Provide more details about your application. Versions of mPDF, larger html/php sample

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this with the code you provided. Try upgrading mPDF to the latest version. If you can, try using a newer PHP version.

Comment: I'm afraid it is caused by the way Scriptcase handles variables. Cannot upgrade php, because Scriptcase doesn't support a higher version yet. Will try to upgrade to latest mpdf.

Answer (score 0):

Here  is the answer:

```
define ("PAGE", chr (123). 'PAGENO}', TRUE);
$mpdf->setFooter(PAGE);
```

Ref: https://forum.scriptcase.com.br/t/resolvido-problema-com-no-pdf/12501